# Need to get a modeless form to show while saving to XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms

So I have an XML file I save to. I cannot for whatever reason get my PleaseWait form to show while this is saving. It gives the perception that my app has frozen.

I am trying the PleaseWait.Show() and the Application.DoEvents() but no luck..

Any ideas??

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSaveNotes.Click
    PleaseWait.Show()
    Application.DoEvents()
    Dim strTime As String
    strTime = Now.ToString
    Dim FileName = Application.StartupPath & "\DATA\" & lblFILEName.Text

    Try

        Dim xmlSIPData As New XmlDocument
        Dim nodeRoot, nodeTroubleInfo, nodeAdditional, nodeDateTimeSaved As XmlNode
        xmlSIPData.Load(FileName)
        nodeRoot = xmlSIPData.SelectSingleNode("//DATA")
        nodeTroubleInfo = nodeRoot.SelectSingleNode("//Info")
        nodeTroubleInfo.InnerText = txtDetails.Text
        nodeAdditional = nodeRoot.SelectSingleNode("//Additional_Notes")
        nodeAdditional.InnerText = txtAdditionalNOTES.Text
        nodeDateTimeSaved = nodeRoot.SelectSingleNode("//DateTimeSaved")
        nodeDateTimeSaved.InnerText = strTime
        xmlSIPData.Save(FileName)

        MsgBox("Note Saved as: " & FileName, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Additional notes saved successfully.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error processing note save. The error was: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error saving information to file.")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    PleaseWait.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't just give the perception that it is frozen, it **is** frozen.  If threading scares you then replace Application.DoEvents() with PleaseWait.Update().

Comment: The .Update() is producing the results I need. Thanks guys! appreciate all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a need to show the `PleaseWait` form if you don't have to.  If you really want to, consider showing the `PleaseWait` with a ShowDialog and then run your code in the OnShown method of the `PleaseWait` form.

Alternatively, you can use a BackgroundWorker to just disable the save button until the saving operation is completed:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim bgw As New BackgroundWorker
  AddHandler bgw.DoWork, AddressOf bgw_DoWork
  AddHandler bgw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bgw_RunWorkerCompleted
  Button1.Enabled = False
  bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
  ' run your code...
  e.Result = "Note was saved."
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
  Button1.Enabled = True
  MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString)
End Sub
```

Another way is by using the new Async and Await methods:

```vb
Private Async Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  Button2.Enabled = False
  Dim result As String = Await SaveFile()
  Button2.Enabled = True
  MessageBox.Show(result)
End Sub

Private Async Function SaveFile() As Task(Of String)
  Await Task.Run(Sub()
                   'run your code...
                 End Sub)
  Return "Note Saved."
End Function
```